# How do I insert image in Heroku Postgres?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, heroku-postgres

I want to make an image database in Heroku but failed.

This is my schema:

[image: schema]

The code I've tried is:

```
 app.post("/create-post", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
    const content = req.body.Content;

    const newMember = Posts.create({
        Owner: req.user.Username,
        Body: req.body.Content,
        Image: req.file
    })
    client.query(`INSERT INTO a_image(data, image, name)VALUES(bytea("${path.join(__dirname, req.file.filename)}"), "${req.file.filename}", "${req.file.originalname}")`, (err, final) => {
        console.log(err, final);
        client.end();
    })

    return res.redirect("/")
})
```

and it returns this error:

```
error: column "C:\Users\The.Peerapon\Desktop\programming\Express-app\uploads\1" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\The.Peerapon\Desktop\programming\Express-app\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\The.Peerapon\Desktop\programming\Express-app\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\The.Peerapon\Desktop\programming\Express-app\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\The.Peerapon\Desktop\programming\Express-app\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  length: 163,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42703',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '52',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '3504',
  routine: 'errorMissingColumn'
} undefined
```

Comment: Typically you _don't_ store an image in the database - you store it in a file bucket (e.g. AWS's S3) and store the _link_ in the database.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't use AWS because it need credit card and I don't have one is there any alternative?

Comment: also I got rejected from AWS educate